# Types of Shoes/Boots in a Medieval Fantasy Desert Culture

Tags: magic, medieval, clothing

For a society that lives primarily in a deep desert environment, what would be the most practical and/or common type of footwear in terms of both style and material?

The world is medieval-ish, but it's fantasy so it's not bound to any specific time or place. I have been trying to get some examples of the types of shoes worn by Bedouins and other desert-dwelling cultures. The Fremen of Arrakis are also a source of inspiration. This is a semi-tribal culture and portions of it are on the move regularly, often on horseback, so it should be a boot or shoe, not a sandal unless a sandal would be no issue on horseback.

Comment: Why would you discard sandals in a desert?

Comment: i remember renan or maybe its Alexp (iam not so sure) give a link regarding this to certain question cant found it though, even upon quick google.

Comment: ah found it! maybe this can help [desert footwear guide](https://secretcompass.com/desert-footwear-guide/) theres other one regarding historical shoes but cant found it, i though it was this one sorry. but i hope the information can help.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica It just seems impractical for horseback, but if it's not, please enlighten me.

Comment: What are you asking? Your title and your body text don't seem to match. Are you asking what the footwear is made out of (materials), or are you asking what type of shoe would work best (design)? Remember, one-specific-question/one-best-answer, so you need to pick *exactly* what you're asking about. (BTW, there are at least six question marks in there. We're lenient... but there's only supposed to be one.)

Comment: @JBH I simplified it, I think. I did not realize I was supposed to limit to a single question. I thought they were all related and that was better than spamming with multiple questions all relating to shoes and their materials. But I will keep that in mind going forward. I hope it's sufficiently narrowed above, though I felt the additional questions were mostly elaborating on the initial question, which is what types of shoe (in terms of material AND style) would make the most sense in a medieval desert environment.

Comment: I can live with this, thanks for the edit. Bear in mind that material often dictates design, so the two aren't as related as you might think. This could easily be split into two questions. (A) Given a desert similar to _______ on Earth, and given that no outside resources are available and a tech level similar to A.D. 500, what natural or synthetic material would be best suited to footwear?" and (B) Given the answer from (A), what shoe design would be most effective for the described environment?" See what I mean?

Comment: Personally, I'm thinking laminate leather of my enemies in stylized knee boots to show off just how many enemies have fallen literally beneath my feet.  I'm just sayin'  :p

Comment: regarding riding horse using sandal, roman cavalry kinda did. also japan samurai, though they have special type of stirrup for it.

Comment: @JBH I would turn that around: design and materials are almost inseperably interlinked. When you create a design for swamps, mountain walks, climbing, silt water walking, poolside relaxation or warm indoor shoes they will vary greatly, and the available material in turn will change the designs. Some designs become impossible without the right materials, some become much more complex or bulky. The question (as posed now) is fairly well constrained without choking it: common medieval times desert footware in a fluff fantasy world.

Comment: @Demigan, My point is, if you don't know what materials to work with, you can't design a shoe. If the best selected option is metal, it'll produce a different design than the only option being snakeskin. If you start with the design, you usually lock yourself into the material. (And to date I'm the only person to up vote the question.... I'm educating, not arguing.)

Comment: @JBH since we know the general area and have a time period to work with you can design the shoes based on anything available during that time period for that area.

Comment: One Amazon tribe dips there feet in rubber from the rubber tree, making bonded perfectly form fitting shoes. there are many strange options for footwear.

Comment: Desert shoes? Either VERY open, allowing ventilation and letting the sand leak out, or serious boots approaching kneeheight, to insulate and keep sand and critters out forever. Historically, humans have used both of these approaches, with sandals being more common due to greatly reduced cost.

Comment: Surely this question can be answered by looking up real historical cultures that lived in or near deserts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In deserts with snakes and scorpions, ankle covering boots are common (although often sandals or bare feet are in use as well.)
In deserts where there are sharp stones, and/or hot sand temperatures, sandals are the least, boots not unheard of.

When your riders (horse, camel, whatever) use metal stirrups, like the ones in use by most riding horses on our world, boots with heels and hard soles are the most wanted footwear. But other kinds of footwear have been used.

But in history, many peoples, spread all over the world, have ridden animals without stirrups or with a different kind of stirrup that does not have the same needs for boots, or even any kind of footwear.

People who walk bare feet all the time have tough skin on the soles of their feet. So if you are inclined against boots, you can have your peoples go bare foot.
On the other hand, you are the writer, if you want your people to wear beautiful boots, by all means have them wear those.

Typically, before rubber became the norm for soles, boots were made out of leather and some sort of yarn made of animal hair or plant fiber. In the making of boots often wood was used to make a last (the form of the foot to build the boot around) but you can invent something else if there is no wood in your world. Some boots will have been made out of wood as well as leather, but it is not needed.
With riding animals you will have leather (from old/butchered riding animals or from other animals used for food.) And adult animals have thick leather, it 'just' has to be tanned in such a way that the thick parts get strong and sturdy.

Dress shoes (at least in the 20'th century) were soled with leather, and walking on streets their soles could last a year or even longer, then you would take them to the cobbler and you would get them re-soled, which would last an other year or two, depending on the use.
Riding boots will not wear as much on most of the soles, though leather should do for them for a year at least, so you may need to 'invent' an easily replaced part where the stirrup damages the sole, or you can just have the readers assume that the whole of the sole will be replaced if needed. (Or leave it out, you will also not describe how often they replace their riding trousers, unless it is vital for the story.)

You can go into the design and making of the boot or leave that out, as fits the story.
But history on earth will have much information.

Go back at least to the pioneers in the USA and those natives who used horses, or the same time or before in Europe, North Africa and Asia, for samples that would fit in your time/tech frame.

Comment: In addition, some hints on [desert footwear design](https://secretcompass.com/desert-footwear-guide/) - uneven terrain with different consistencies; concerns - blisters, bruises, sand/gravel getting in, ankle support. Make the sole tough (to resist penetration) yet flexible (to reduce blisters). Shoe should climb up on the calf (stop the sand getting in and those critters to find a spot to inject their venom) - above ankle in any case

Comment: Farmers in the Netherlands are among the last clog users, their ground is usually uneven and can have surprises. Good fitting clogs do not give any more blisters than good fitting boots. Dutch clogs are wood only.

Comment: But often filled with straw, especially in winters.

Comment: Good fitting clogs do not have space nor need for straw.